# How to convert horizontal dataframe structure to vertical - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a script that read a .xlsx file and create a dataframe that looks like this

```
index|TASK|CODE|NAME|WT|ST|ORIGIN|SRV|DESTINY|FT|MCLINE|ST.1|ORIGIN.1|SRV.1|DESTINY.1|FT.1|MCLINE.1
```

This could be longer depending in the columns of excel file and just repeating the fields `ST.(n)`, `ORIGIN.(n)`, `SRV.(n)`, `DESTINY.(n)`, `FT.(n)`, `MCLINE.(n))`

For Example

| index | TASK | CODE | NAME | WT | ST | ORIGIN | SRV | DESTINY | FT | MCLINE | ST.1 | ORIGIN.1 | SRV.1 | DESTINY.1 | FT.1 | MCLINE.1 | ST.2 | ORIGIN.2 | SRV.2 | DESTINY.2 | FT.2 | MCLINE.2 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 61P00QH | 12900 | CROUCH, PETER | 06:14 | 14:46 | Pat Col | 61P004T | Pat Col | 16:06 | Etap 1-R*G0431 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 61P00CH | 10900 | LAMPARD, FRANK | 07:13 | 06:20 | Pat Col | 61P00CT | Pat Col | 09:53 | Etap 1-R*D0431 | 10:33 | Pat Col | 61P00CT | Pat Col | 14:13 | Etapa 1-R*D0431 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 5SE00DH | 18049 | GERRARD, STEVEN | 07:30 | 11:55 | Grand Station | 5SE005O | Grand Station | 16:01 | Grand station*D0290/Copa*D0291 | 16:41 | Grand Station | 5SE003O | Grand Station | 17:37 | No | 17:41 | Grand Station | 5SE009O | Pat Oda | 19:55 | Grand Station*D0290/Copa*D0291 |  |

My desired output should be like this

| index | TASK | CODE | NAME | WT | ST | ORIGIN | SRV | DESTINY | FT | MCLINE |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 61P00QH | 12900 | CROUCH, PETER | 06:14 | 14:46 | Pat Col | 61P004T | Pat Col | 16:06 | Etap 1-R*G0431 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 61P00CH | 10900 | LAMPARD, FRANK | 07:13 | 06:20 | Pat Col | 61P00CT | Pat Col | 09:53 | Etap 1-R*D0431 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 61P00CH | 10900 | LAMPARD, FRANK | 07:13 | 10:33 | Pat Col | 61P00CT | Pat Col | 14:13 | Etap 1-R*D0431 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 5SE00DH | 18049 | GERRARD, STEVEN | 07:30 | 11:55 | Grand Station | 5SE005O | Grand Station | 16:01 | Grand station*D0290/Copa*D0291 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 5SE00DH | 18049 | GERRARD, STEVEN | 07:30 | 16:41 | Grand Station | 5SE003O | Grand Station | 17:37 | No |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | 5SE00DH | 18049 | GERRARD, STEVEN | 07:30 | 17:41 | Grand Station | 5SE009O | Pat Oda | 19:55 | Grand Station*D0290/Copa*D0291 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Now I'm creating manually a new dataframe and renaming the columns and deleting null rows for "ST"  and then just concatenating the dataframe to obtain all the information  but it's slow and not really good. I'm searching for a way to do it faster and efficiently as I will have to do it quite often.

Comment: how big can "n" be? or you need to be ready to any value?

Comment: I need to be ready for any value.

Comment: ok, have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Well I was trying to use this but I dont know how to do it.

df.replace('', np.nan).set_index(['CODE','NAME']).stack().reset_index(name='H.INICIAL').drop('level_1',1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case for `pandas.wide_to_long`. But we need a little adjustment first, since this function needs all similar columns to be named under the same pattern, *i.e.* `<COLNAME.N>`. Here we go:

```
import pandas as pd

# import your data into a dataframe df

common_cols = ['ST', 'ORIGIN', 'SRV', 'DESTINY', 'FT', 'MCLINE']

df = df.rename({col: col + '.0' for col in common_cols}, axis=1)

_df = (pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=common_cols,
                       i=['TASK', 'CODE', 'NAME', 'WT'],
                       j='n',
                       suffix=r'\.\d*')
       .reset_index()
       .drop('n', axis=1)
       .dropna())
```

The result is as follows:

```
      TASK   CODE            NAME     WT     ST        ORIGIN      SRV       DESTINY     FT                         MCLINE
0  61P00QH  12900    CROUCH,PETER  06:14  14:46        PatCol  61P004T        PatCol  16:06                  Etap1-R*G0431
3  61P00CH  10900   LAMPARD,FRANK  07:13  06:20        PatCol  61P00CT        PatCol  09:53                  Etap1-R*D0431
4  61P00CH  10900   LAMPARD,FRANK  07:13  10:33        PatCol  61P00CT        PatCol  14:13                 Etapa1-R*D0431
6  5SE00DH  18049  GERRARD,STEVEN  07:30  11:55  GrandStation  5SE005O  GrandStation  16:01  Grandstation*D0290/Copa*D0291
7  5SE00DH  18049  GERRARD,STEVEN  07:30  16:41  GrandStation  5SE003O  GrandStation  17:37                             No
8  5SE00DH  18049  GERRARD,STEVEN  07:30  17:41  GrandStation  5SE009O        PatOda  19:55  GrandStation*D0290/Copa*D0291
```